# A way to identify a socket in OnClientConnect event?

Tags: delphi, winsock

I have a client, and i want the server to (from advanced) identify him in the OnClientConnect event, is it possible ?

do i need to do something in the OnConnect event of TClientSocket ?

for example, if i send a string from the onconnect (client side) event it would reach the onclientread event (server-side), instead of i want to know if there's any way to make it reach the onclientconnect event.

if there's a neater way, please let me know. ;]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `TServerSocket` in non-blocking mode (its default mode), then you have to wait for the `OnClientRead` event to do any reading.  You can use the `TCustomWinSocket.Data` property to keep track of whether you have read the first string or not.  You could initialize that tracking in the `OnClientConnect` event and then update it in the `OnClientRead` event. If other code needs to access the client, don't do anything with it until that first string has been read.

Another thing to consider - Imagine if a client connected and did not send anything. If your server blocks itself waiting for the string in that event, that would create an entry point for a DOS attack.  The `OnClientConnect` event would not be a good place to do the read.

If you absolutely need to do the read in the `OnClientConnect` event, then switch the `TServerSocket` into thread-blocking mode instead.

Comment: it is not a must, i just wanted to know if it's possible, that is all, thanks anyhow.

Comment: Possible, yes, if you enter into a busy loop doing the reading until the string actually arrives, but that is not ideal to do in non-blocking mode since it blocks the entire server while the loop is running. In non-blocking mode, you have to use the events so the server stays responsive.

Comment: Yeah that's polling and blocking other events, not a good idea. -.-"